# Yosemite: ssh slow to connect when using DNS alias

Tags: macos, ssh, dns

Since updating to Yosemite, ssh from my Mac to a DNS alias takes about 7-8 seconds.

I've observed the following on multiple Macs running Yosemite. Assume I have a host name **alpha**, and a DNS alias to it named **aa**. The OS of the target doesn't matter.

1) ssh to an unqualified host name alias (CNAME record in DNS), e.g. *ssh aa*, takes about 7-8 seconds to connect
2) immediately repeating the same ssh command, *ssh aa*, connects in the "normal" amount of time (< 1s)
3) ssh to a fully qualified host name alias, e.g. *ssh aa.example.com*, connects in the normal amount of time
4) ssh to a regular host name (A record in DNS), e.g. *ssh alpha.example.com*, whether qualified or unqualified, connects in the normal amount of time.

When using *ssh -vvv*, the total delay is in one place:

```
$ ssh -vv aa
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    *delay of 7-8 seconds*
debug1: Connecting to aa [10.10.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
```

There is no difference in output between any of the 4 scenarios, except for the host name displayed.

This has happened on every release of Yosemite to the current version 10.10.3.

I have searched the web many times, and not found a single reference to this problem. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a “fix” for this, though it still doesn't explain anything.

In our organization, we have “standard” DNS arranged hierarchically for different sites, just as you would expect. We *also* have an Active Directory structure that is largely flat. The resolv.conf (actually defined in Network Settings) had my local DNS domain listed as a search domain. I discovered quite by accident that adding the AD domain as a search domain fixes the problem!

So now I have something like:

```
search mysite.example.com ad.example.com
```

Now ssh’ing to an unqualified alias takes no more time than any other form of the host name.

Really bizarre, and I have no idea why this fixes it.